How to convert table data to JSON in postgresql
I want to create JSON using two tables.
I'm a SQL beginner so it's difficult to create. This is Google Translate. sorry.
create table data_tb (city text , val_2020 numeric , val_2021 numeric);

insert into data_tb values ('korea seoul', 80.00, 73.91);
insert into data_tb values ('korea busan', 79.28, 70.27);

create table unit_tb (unit text, ranges text);
insert into unit_tb values ('%', '0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80');

I want to create JSON like this using SQL
{
    data:[
        {
            label: 'val_2020', 
            chartData: [{
                    key: 'korea seoul',
                    value: 80.00
                },
                {
                    key: 'korea busan',
                    value: 79.28
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'val_2021', 
            chartData: [{
                    key: 'korea seoul',
                    value: 73.91
                },
                {
                    key: 'korea busan',
                    value: 70.27
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    unit: '%',
    ranges: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
}


Try this:  https://dbfiddle.uk/fEjXNmru

A bit complex and messy. Maybe the data design can be optimized.
select jsonb_build_object(
 'data', jsonb_build_array(
 jsonb_build_object(
    'label', 'val_2020', 
    'chartData', (select jsonb_agg(t) 
                  from (select city as key, val_2020 as value from data_tb) t)),
 jsonb_build_object(    'label', 'val_2021', 
    'chartData', (select jsonb_agg(t)
                  from (select city as key, val_2021 as value from data_tb) t))),
 'unit', (select unit from unit_tb),
 'ranges', ('{'||(select ranges from unit_tb)||'}')::integer[]
);

DB Fiddle demo
